# Search a row from a table which starts with asterisk symbol

Tags: c#

I am uploading an excel file by using c# and i am selecting a column named LOT from that excel file.In column LOT one row is having number starting with asterisk symbol(*). I need a query to select all the rows. please Help me out in this.

I tried the below sample code but it is not working fine. Its returning the lots which doesn't have asterisk symbol(*).

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get path from web.config file to upload
    string FilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();

    string filename = string.Empty;
    //To check whether file is selected or not to uplaod
    if (BrowseFile.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] allowdFile = { ".xls", ".xlsx" };
            //Here we are allowing only excel file so verifying selected file pdf or not
            string FileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(BrowseFile.PostedFile.FileName);
            //Check whether selected file is valid extension or not
            bool isValidFile = allowdFile.Contains(FileExt);
            if (!isValidFile)
            {
                lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblMsg.Text = "Please upload only Excel";
            }
            else
            {
                // Get size of uploaded file, here restricting size of file
                int FileSize = BrowseFile.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                if (FileSize <= 1048576)//1048576 byte = 1MB
                {
                    //Get file name of selected file
                    filename = Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(BrowseFile.FileName));

                    //Save selected file into server location
                    BrowseFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FilePath) + filename);
                    //Get file path
                    string filePath = Server.MapPath(FilePath) + filename;
                    //Open the connection with excel file based on excel version
                    OleDbConnection con = null;
                    if (FileExt == ".xls")
                    {
                        con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

                    }
                    else if (FileExt == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
                    }
                    con.Open();
                    //Get the list of sheet available in excel sheet
                    DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    //Get first sheet name
                    string getExcelSheetName = dt.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                    //Select rows from first sheet in excel sheet and fill into dataset
                    //OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT LOT FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] WHERE LOT IS NOT NULL", con);
                    OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT LOT FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] WHERE LOT LIKE '**'", con);
                    OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);
                    DataTable ExcelDataSet = new DataTable();
                    ExcelAdapter.Fill(ExcelDataSet);
                    //Holding the data into the list
                    List<DataRow> strLot = ExcelDataSet.AsEnumerable().ToList();
                    con.Close();
                    //string lots = "";
                    //seperating the each lot with a comma separator
                    for (int i = 0; i < strLot.Count; i++)
                    {
                        totLots += ExcelDataSet.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString() + ",";
                    }
                    //Removing the last comma separator
                    totLots = totLots.Remove(totLots.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LIKE operator

> `WHERE <Column> LIKE '\**'`

Also, depending on your data source, the wildcard `'*'` could be replaced with `'%'` and `'LIKE'` keyword could be replaced with `'ALIKE'`

with `'%'` the search text will become `'*%'` instead of `'\**'`

**Edit: Code below checked with .xls and .xlsx files**

```
OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT LOT FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] WHERE LOT LIKE '*%'", con);
```

Comment: When i am using this it is returning count as zero as i have one row with asterisk before.Help me out in this if possible

Comment: i did as u asked to do but i am getting zero value only.

Comment: can you share the project and the sample excel file, somehow

Comment: i shared my piece of code ... help me out in this as i spent two days working on it.

Comment: Manish, still its returning zero value for count after using '*%' as i have one row with asterisk symbol in excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

Change your command text to the following...

```
@"SELECT [LOT] FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] WHERE [LOT] LIKE '\*%')"
```

This should preform [a simple pattern match like a SQL script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and look for any member of the column starting with an asterisk and containing anything at all after that.

Comment: when i am using this it is returning row count as zero as i have one row with asterisk in excel sheet under column LOT. Help me out in this if possible.

Comment: I may be wrong, but, does the value starts with * or '* in the cell.... ' is a special character in Excel which is not displayed by default, so please check the function bar to see what the value actually is (or edit the cell to see the actual value in the cell)

Comment: i checked as u said but i din find any '(single quote) in the cell.It starts with *(asterisk) only.